# Merge Sort Time in C

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, ubuntu, mergesort

This is my virtual machine:

CPU: 4 cores
RAM: 4096 MB
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit)

### Problem1: Why there is a threshold 4193790?

I write a merge sort in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include"helper.c"
#define N 4193789

void merge(double* li,int left1,int right1,int left2,int right2,int size){
    double *li_tmp;
    li_tmp = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    int i = left1;
    int j = left2;
    int k = left1;

    while(i<=right1 && j<=right2){ 
        if(li[i] < li[j]){
            li_tmp[k] = li[i++]; 
        }     
        else{
            li_tmp[k] = li[j++];
        } 
        k++; 
    }
    if(i>right1){
        while(j<=right2){
            li_tmp[k++] = li[j++];
        }
    }
    else if(j>right2){
        while(i<=right1){
            li_tmp[k++] = li[i++];
        }
    }

    for(i=left1; i<right2+1; i++){
        li[i] = li_tmp[i];
    }
    free(li_tmp); 
}

void merge_sort(double* li,int left,int right,int size){
    if (left<right){        
        int mid = (left + right)/2;
        merge_sort(li,left,mid,size);
        merge_sort(li,mid+1,right,size);
        merge(li,left,mid,mid+1,right,size);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Just call merge_sort(), check the correctness and print the time consumption.
    double *data;
    data = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*N);
    srand(1234567);
    gen_rand(data,N);

    struct timeval start, end;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    merge_sort(data, 0, N-1, N);

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    double delta = ((end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec) * 1000000u + end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1.e6;

    bool correct = true;
    for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++){
        if (data[i]>data[i+1]){
            correct = false;
        }
    }
    if (correct){
        printf("Correct!\n");
    }else{
        printf("Not correct!\n");
    }

    printf("time spent=%12.10f\n",delta);
}
```

This is my helper.c, just generate a random double array in double *a.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

void gen_rand(double *a, int num){
    for (int i=0;i<num;i++){
        a[i] = 1.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX * num;
    }
}
```

I found a very weird scenario:
I know that merge sort is O(nlogn), so when I experiment with different array lengths, I find that the time consumption varies a lot in one area, and it doesn't fit O(nlogn).After many attempts, I found a threshold.
**When I define N as 4193789, the time is 1s, but when I change N to 4193790, the time will increase to 34s!**
I wonder why there is such a threshold.

```
vagrant@hang2:~/data/$ gcc -fopenmp merge_sort_main.c 
vagrant@hang2:~/data/$ ./a.out 
Correct!
time spent=1.1103340000
vagrant@hang2:~/data/$ gcc -fopenmp merge_sort_main.c 
vagrant@hang2:~/data/$ ./a.out 
Correct!
time spent=34.5053590000
```

---

### Problem2: Why the omp method get slower when a big array (more than 4193790)?

Another problem with omp:
This is my omp main :

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
    #pragma omp single 
        merge_sort_omp(data, 0, N-1, N);
    }
```

And merge_sort_omp():

```
void merge_sort_omp(double* li,int left,int right,int size){
    if (left<right){
        if (right-left>10000){        
            int mid = (left + right)/2;
            #pragma omp task firstprivate (li, left, mid)
            merge_sort_omp(li,left,mid,size);
            #pragma omp task firstprivate (li, mid, right)
            merge_sort_omp(li,mid+1,right,size);
            #pragma omp taskwait
            merge(li,left,mid,mid+1,right,size);
        }else{
            int mid = (left + right)/2;
            merge_sort_omp(li,left,mid,size);
            merge_sort_omp(li,mid+1,right,size);
            merge(li,left,mid,mid+1,right,size);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried N=4000000 and N=4193790 as follows:

```
vagrant@hang2:~/data$ gcc -fopenmp merge_sort_main.c 
vagrant@hang2:~/data$ ./a.out 
Correct!
time spent=1.1358180000
vagrant@hang2:~/data$ gcc -fopenmp merge_sort_omp_main.c 
vagrant@hang2:~/data$ ./a.out 
Correct!
time spent=0.4998150000
vagrant@hang2:~/data$ gcc -fopenmp merge_sort_main.c 
vagrant@hang2:~/data$ ./a.out 
Correct!
time spent=34.3504340000
vagrant@hang2:~/data$ gcc -fopenmp merge_sort_omp_main.c 
vagrant@hang2:~/data$ ./a.out 
Correct!
time spent=111.9368700000
```

I want to know why the parallel code is twice as fast as the serial code at N= 4000000, but the serial code is slower at N=4193790. Almost three times slower. I want to know why the omp get slower?

Comment: Your loop checking for correctness is wrong, as it increase `i` twice each iteration. It means e.g. `data[1]` can be less than `data[2]` and you would not notice.

Comment: As for your problem, I suggest you test with other sizes as well, and try to find a pattern. For example even versus odd size? Also using random data could lead to corner cases  that exhibits the bad or good properties of the sorting algorithm. I suggest you create a fixed set of well-distributed data that you can use in full or a part of.

Comment: Oh and a very important thing to remember when doing benchmarking: Always benchmark *optimized* builds! You don't use OpenMP in your code, so remove that header and flag, but add the `-O3` flag to make sure the compiler optimizes your code.

Comment: _Side note:_ Doing multiple/many `malloc/free` in `merge` for `li_tmp` is going to be slow. Better to do a _single_ `malloc/free` in the outermost function [with the initial/maximum count] and pass it as an argument.

Comment: Also, the way you have it now you allocate a temp buffer of size `size` (never reduced) in each recursive call - this is inefficient. Only allocate a buffer of the size that you are actually sorting.

Comment: Please compile with `-O2` or `-O3` to maximize the optimizations. It's highly possible your code will be an order of magnitude faster when optimizations are applied.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have another question about omp, but I want to deal with this problem first. My focus is why there is an threshold 4193790 and 4193789. Why does the array length increase by 1, but the time consumption increases by 30 seconds?

Comment: Could be (???) data dependant. Does it happen at the same number with `srand(20210916);`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with random numbers, I tried different srand() but the same threshold 4193790.

Comment: The increase probably represents a trigger for malloc, where below a certain size, it caches allocations, and beyond it allocates / releases the memory back to the system.   If you try the suggestions of @CraigEstey you will see times level out.

Comment: @mevets I modified OP's original single threaded code to do a single `malloc/free` -- I got a time reduction [on my system] from 1.01 to 0.8. Also, I think the threshold is system/machine dependent because I didn't get the "cliff" effect on my system (which has 12GB of ram)

Comment: @CraigEstey I straced it on mine, and under the cliff it was doing a few dozen mmap() anons; over the cliff it was doing millions...

Comment: @mevets Thanks! Your answer really helped me! I have modified my code , and the "cliff" 4293790 is disappeared.

Comment: The omp one will have a similar result -- almost 3 times slower, because it is doing 4x (I guess you have 4 cores ) the number of alloc + free.  By going to a single buffer, you will mess up omp considerably; so you either have to manage the buffers -- you only need a tmp of (right - left) for a given merege -- or figure out how to get omp to manage them.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the calls to build with `-O2` or `-O3` in the comments, the most expensive thing your code is doing is calling `malloc` and `free` to build a temporary array on every invocation of `merge_sort`. Memory allocations being done on each iteration of a high-performance loop can slow things down greatly.

The easy fix is just do a single allocation of that temp buffer exactly once - and to make it big enough for all scenarios.

Instead of this:

```
void merge(double* li,int left1,int right1,int left2,int right2,int size){
    double *li_tmp;
    li_tmp = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
```

This:

```
double* li_tmp = NULL;  // li_tmp is now global

void merge(double* li,int left1,int right1,int left2,int right2,int size){

    if (li_tmp == NULL) {
        li_tmp = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*N); // allocate for size N just once
    }
```

Then remove the `free` statement at the bottom of the merge function.

Instead of this:

```
    for(i=left1; i<right2+1; i++){
        li[i] = li_tmp[i];
    }
    free(li_tmp); 
}
```

Just this:

```
    for(i=left1; i<right2+1; i++){
        li[i] = li_tmp[i];
    }
    
}
```

Then free li_tmp elsewhere after the merge-sort has run to completion.

As to why different sizes for `N` cause different perf changes, I don't think that's worth getting into without these optimizations and compiler switches applied.  The most likely hypothesis is that the array sizes caused by different sizes of N, trigger more "paging" between cache memory and main RAM.  Or these large block allocations stress the memory manager in different ways.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Now the threshold 4293790 is disappeared. Apart from this, I also would like to know why the frequent `malloc` will lead to a threshold?

Comment: Which had bigger impact?  The `-O3` switch or the removal of the frequent `malloc`?  But my guess is that the block sizes caused the memory manager to work harder to keep the heap in a good state and/or triggered more system calls to pull memory managed by the OS into the process heap.

Comment: Yeah that's memory's thing. I moved the `malloc` outside and everything goes well.